# Смельчак - храбрец

Tags: выбор-слова

Чем отличаются слова смельчак и храбрец?

Comment: "смельчак" is something like "a brave person"... and "храбрец" is something like "a courageous person"—Google says a daredevil vs. a lionheart—seems to fit this situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти понятия во многом пересекаются, но есть ситуации, для которых одно из этих слов уместнее:

Смельчак - человек, готовый пойти на риск в расчёте на удачу и свои силы (готовность ввязаться в борьбу).

Храбрец - человек, действующий бесстрашно, попав в сложную ситуацию (готовность бороться).

Иными словами, можно "смело в бой пойти" (как в песне поётся) и затем "храбро сражаться".

Answer (score 1):

Я не считаю, что здесь есть какая-то существенная разница. Однако слово "смельчак", засчёт суффикса -ак, звучит как чуть более эмоционально окрашенное (приземлённое) слово, чем "храбрец", с вытекающими отсюда коннотациями, у каждого своими (см. ответ Alex_ander). Толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова, например, не даёт никакой разницы: "СМЕЛЬЧАК, -а; м. Смелый человек; храбрец"

Храбрец - заимствование из церковнославянского, смельчак - исконно русское слово. Это просто дублеты.

Comment: Из церковнославянского заимствована только современная форма "храбрый". Форма же "хоробрый" вполне русская, да и вообще, оба слова имеют праславянские корни.

Comment: @user4419802 так, но мы ж не говорим хоробрец, а "хоробрый" - устаревшая, неиспользуемая форма.

Comment: спасибо за эти устаревшие слова!

Answer (score 1):

В настоящее время оба слова употребляются взаимозаменяемо. Тем не менее, некая разница между ними должна была иметь место, так как оба слова являются общими для всех славян.

"Смельчак" очевидно связан со "сметь", "осмелиться", то есть "смелость" - это изначально духовная черта, ближе всего к "решимости".

Со словом "храбрец" всё сложнее. Но даже если оно и не связано с "быстрый", "острый" и пр., всё-таки некая связь именно с "храбростью в сражении" кажется здесь более выраженной.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести какие-то примеры, подтверждающие то, что  храбрый общеславянское слово?

Comment: @shabunc Не совсем понял, что Вы имеете в виду. Храбрый-хоробрый-хоробрий-храбар-chrobry и т.п. очевидно восходят к общему праславянскому корню.

Answer (score 1):

Слово `смелость` скорее всего пошло от `суметь` (он сумел). Прилагательное `сумелый`. То есть оказаться в состоянии сделать что-либо. И это от глагола.

```
Как ты смеешь мне дерзить?
```

Имеется ввиду что он осмелился высказать то что он думает.

Слово `храбрость` имеет значение не жалея себя.

```
Он смело пошел в бой и храбро сражался.
```

Тут имеется ввиду что он решился вступить в бой и сражался не жалея своей жизни. Значения у слов разные.